# pl/sql need to know the techniques behind

Tags: sql, join, sql-update

May I know wat kind of technique used in below to update and how it works

This question has been taken from our forum::

```
update  demo_table new 
set     (new.quantity, new.actual_cost) = 
        (
        SELECT  old.quantity, old.actual_cost
        FROM    demo_table old
        WHERE   old.object_name = new.object_name
            and old.object_type = new.object_type
            and old.trans_date = new.trans_date
            and old.trans_type = 1
)
where new.trans_type = 9
```

Comment: What do you mean by "technique"? It's an update query with a sub query.

Comment: Thanks :) How tat works and getting update

Comment: This is a query written in the PL/SQL language. You need to read a few chapters of a beginner's guide and then you will understand what is going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a basic structure of how an update query works:

```
UPDATE tableName SET column = value WHERE condition = true;
```

In your case, you're updating the `demo_table new` table with a condition of `new.trans_type = 9`.

The tricky thing here is you're using your sub query as your value to set the columns as. A sub query is basically another query that would return a result. In this case, your sub query is a `select` statement from the `demo_table old` table.

Comment: Consider some upvoting or accepting if this helped ;)